# If statement doesn't work when checking for file content

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to check if "C:\test.txt" exists *or* if "Done" is present in that file. If not, set domain policy and create file "C:\test.txt" and write "Done" to it.

If I use both conditions...

```
if (!(Select-String -Path c:\test.txt -Pattern "Done") -or !(Test-Path C:\log.txt)) {
    Set-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy -Identity ad.contoso.com -ComplexityEnabled $true -MinPasswordLength 7 -MinPasswordAge 1 -MaxPasswordAge 30 -LockoutDuration 00:30:00 -LockoutObservationWindow 00:30:00 -LockoutThreshold 3
    write-output "test" | out-file C:\Users\tfl.AD\Desktop\test.txt -Append
}
```

Then I get:

> ```
> Select-String : Cannot find path 'C:\test.txt' because it does not exist.
> ```

`Set-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy` has no output, that's why I added second command to write `Done` to `log.txt`

Comment: Put the `Test-Path` statement first; that way if the file doesn't exist, you won't attempt to read from it.

Comment: silly, but this worked,thanks !

Comment: We don't add SOLVED in titles here. It is not necessary as that is what the check mark is for.

Comment: oh !, sorry, didn't know it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As JohnLBevan say in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53171879/powershell-if-statement-doesnt-work-when-checking-for-file-content#comment93233437_53171879) you should switch the order of clauses around `-or`.

```
$filetoCheck = "C:\test.txt"
!(Test-Path $filetoCheck) -or !(Select-String -Path $filetoCheck -Pattern "Done")
```

So if the file does not exist then the righthand side of that statement will not need to be executed. You get a longer explanation from [about_logical_operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logical_operators?view=powershell-6)

> The PowerShell logical operators evaluate only the statements required to determine the truth value of the statement. If the left operand in a statement that contains the and operator is FALSE, the right operand is not evaluated. **If the left operand in a statement that contains the or statement is TRUE, the right operand is *not* evaluated**. As a result, you can use these statements in the same way that you would use the If statement.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

---

You also mention that

> `Set-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy` has no output

That is true... by *default*. Many cmdlets, like `Set-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy`, support the `-PassThru` switch. So if you wanted to you could output some or part of the object passed through the pipeline.

```
Set-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy -Identity ad.contoso.com .... -PassThru | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation c:\log.csv -Append
```

You might need to add a `Select` in there to get the exact output that would satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to `Select-String` like:

```
Select-String -Path c:\test.txt -Pattern "Done" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

or use `Test-Path` first.

Comment: But `SilentlyContinue` would hide other errors too, e.g. when access is denied.